# highstock mouse releaase trendline

Tags: mouse, highcharts

i have to draw trendlines based on user selections. meaning user presses mouse.. draggs and releases on the end point.. then draw lines..
highcharts does not have any mouse release event.. so i am adding that to chart container.
the problem is how can i convert pageX and pageY to chart SVG coordinates..

i am using following code for mouse click(chart click event)

```
chart: {
events: {
  click: function(event) {
      alert (
         'x: '+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', event.xAxis[0].value) +', ' +
                    'y: '+ event.yAxis[0].value
            );
    }
```

}

how can i do this on mouse release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Highcharts you have selection event, when you can add plotLines or plotBands, see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.selection).

Also, check [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail) example - it has implemented in bottom chart (these are two separate charts) this you almost need.

Comment: tried this.. but selection would not work without setting zoom type. i do want exact same thing.. but should work without zoom type. so i can get start and end points and draw trendline(by adding new series)..how can i do that ?

Comment: You can disable default behavior, see: http://jsfiddle.net/TMtwD/ Just use `event.preventDefault();` Adding new series, calculating values etc will be harder, I think?

Comment: instead i manage to draw line on second click on chart..its working fine.. but when user clicks on series, chart click event does not get fire...what should i need to get selected mouse co-ordinates even if mouse is on series. below is the example that i am working on          http://jsfiddle.net/amit_shah25/EQ8aH/

Comment: I think you need to use `series.events.click` or `point.events.click` the same function as for `chart.events.click`, [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.click).

Comment: thanks a lot.. that did the trick and its working fine.but another issue i found that.. when i zoom in chart or use chart navigator.. lines are not sticky... how can i make them visible even if user is zooming into chart..?

Comment: is there a way i can convert chartX and chartY (SVG co-ordinates) to proper xAxis.value and yAxis.value ? then i can update and re-draw after zoom.. also is there another way to draw line besides renderer.path which really takes axis co-ordinates ?

Comment: Instead of renderer path, use series, and add points for clicks? To convert chartX/Y use `chart.x/yAxis[0].toValues(chartX/Y);`

Comment: toValues(..).. i was looking for this one..is there a event which tells me when user zooms chart.. i am adding too many series.and dont want to keep redrawing the lines.. which i have to if i use redraw function.